# Почему JSP имеет доступ к приватным полям объекта?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Есть класс с приватными полями. Если передать объект такого класса JSP странице, то JSP-страница будет иметь доступ к приватным полям объекта. Почему так происходит?

```
public class Main {
  private int value;
  private String str;

  public int getValue(){
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  publi String getStr(){
    return str;
  }

  public void setStr(String str) {
    this.str = str;
  }
}

// передаем объект jsp странице
Main obj = new Obj();
obj.setValue(42);
obj.setStr("42");

req.setAttribute("obj", obj);
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/page.jsp").forward(req, resp);

// page.jsp
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p><c:out value="${obj.value}"/></p>
  <p><c:out value="${obj.str}"/></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JSP использует get методы для получения значений private полей. К примеру поле под названием name будет доступно из JSP по геттеру getName(), если же вы не правильно назовете метод( к примеру getNames()) то jsp страница просто не найдет ваше поле!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ничего подобного.

```
obj.value;
```

Эта запись означат, что будет вызван `метод-геттер` для поля `value` объекта `obj`.

Т.е подобную запись следует воспринимать вот так:

`obj.get`**`Value`**`();`

Comment: @Other делаю откат, так как форматирование для кода сожрало жирность выделенного фрагмента, который я намеренно выделил

Comment: В коде лучше не использовать подобные средства форматирования, опишите значимость словами, если нужно. Но дело Ваше.

Comment: Я обычно в таких ситуациях использую комментарии со стрелочками, выровненными по важной секции кода, вроде `//       ^^^^^`, чем-то похоже на формат вывода ошибок Clang (на [скриншоте](https://www.ishani.org/public/images/projects/cvsx2013_output.png) внизу).

Answer (score 1):

Доступ к приватным полям возможен в данном случае, т.к. для этих полей есть публичные геттеры. Это так же, как способность наследника получать доступ к приватным полям предка через публичные геттеры предка, которые наследник унаследовал.